# How to install gcc 8.2.1 on Fedora 31

Tags: python, fedora, gcc

I tried to install CUDA on fedora 31 but got stuck at the last step because CUDA officially support fedora 29 (gcc 8.2) while the version shipped with fedora 31 is 9.2, I then installed pytorch with cuda support and without much surprise, CUDA support is not present

```
>>> import torch
>>> device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
>>> device
device(type='cpu')
```

I then tried to search for gcc, g++ and gfortran on [pkgs](https://pkgs.org/), but got stuck in a dependency hell, something like:

```
sudo dnf install gcc-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm gcc-gfortran-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm gcc-c++-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm -y

Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides cpp = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
  - nothing provides libgomp = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libgfortran = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-gfortran-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
  - nothing provides libquadmath = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-gfortran-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
  - nothing provides libquadmath-devel = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-gfortran-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
 Problem 3: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libstdc++ = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-c++-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++-devel = 8.2.1-2.fc29 needed by gcc-c++-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64
```

I found a bunch helpful links on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4) but unfortunately the last version is gcc 7.3
My last option is building from source, but apart from that is there any other option ? I'm not sure my computer can handle the compilation in a decent amount of time.

Comment: Dependency Hell. But you want to install the whole of the Planet of _Mars_ at once using a nice One-Liner such as "`sudo dnf install gcc-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm gcc-gfortran-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm gcc-c++-8.2.1-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm -y`". We would eat first _GCC_, then _Fortran_, then _C++_, then all of the rest. Try with only one Software Package at once.